# R - Normal distribution with top 10% larger than specific value

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I need to simulate a roughly normally distributed sample in R of size 500. 10%, i.e., 50 of the values should be larger than 50, the rest should be below 50 but still larger than 0.

I'm kind of stuck... any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You can never guarantee that a normal distribution will have all its members greater than 0, since its pdf is symmetrical about the mean and is strictly non-zero everywhere.

Comment: This is not really an R question, nor even a programming question. You would do better to ask this question on (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Allan you're right, let me rephrase my question

Comment: @GSW, I would like to have the respective R-code that's why I asked this here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this. First of all, take 502 samples:

```r
x <- rnorm(502)
```

Now normalize the output so that the minimum is 0 and maximum is 1:

```
x <- x - min(x)
x <- x / max(x)
```

Since the 0 and 1 are not random, we remove them from the sample:

```
x <- x[-c(which.min(x), which.max(x))]
```

Now we multiply the result by whichever number causes 10% of the sample to be greater than 50. We can use `optimize` for this:

```r
f <- function(a) abs(sum((a * x) > 50)/length(x) - 0.1)
x <- optimize(f, c(0, 100))$minimum * x
```

This gives us what appears to be a normally distributed sample:

```r
hist(x)
```

[image]

And exactly 10% of the samples are above 50:

```r
length(x)
#> [1] 500

sum(x > 50)
#> [1] 50
```

None of the samples are less than 0:

```r
min(x)
#> [1] 6.299734
```

And the result is not statistically different from a normal distribution:

```r
shapiro.test(x)
#> 
#>  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 
#> data:  x
#> W = 0.99769, p-value = 0.7275
```

---

**Addendum**

Incidentally, if you only need a single sample, a quick alternative is:

```r
set.seed(4)
x <- rnorm(500, 35.3, 12)
```

Here, `x` is normally distributed with a minimum value of 1.22 and exactly 50 elements are over 50.